# Избежание ошибки 429 C#

Tags: c#, http, httpclient, anglesharp

Как избежать ошибки 429 при более 20 запросах? У меня есть массив со строками, который я отправляю на сервер. Сервер не может принимать более 3к символов за раз, поэтому одной огромной строкой отправить не могу. Что делать?

```
var currentUrl = url + text.ToString();

var response = await client.GetAsync(currentUrl);
string source = "";

if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    source = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

return source;
```

Comment: Используйте Post-запрос и вкладывайте `text` в Request body

Comment: А можно ссылку на пример? Я не очень силен в http, поэтому не особо понимаю.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Для этого надо предварительно уточнить у топикстартера, его ли это сервер и отвечает ли он по POST - раз, также как на GET - два. У меня впечатление, что это не его сервер, а это проект по парсингу чужого сайта (типовое использование AngleSharp), иначе бы к себе API было бы какое-никакое. А значит, что не факт, что ваш способ подойдёт

Comment: @AK Так и есть. Я пытаюсь отправить запрос на гугл и получить ответ.

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS какой ответ вы хотите получить от google? Какой url используете и для каких целей вы посылаете такую большую строку?